# Azure Batch : Server failed to authenticate the request when trying to create pool using Python SDk

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch

It works when I try to create a pool in a particular virtual network subnet using the Azure Portal UI, I am able to access other VMs on the same subnet from these compute nodes. But if I try to do the same using Python SDK like this:

```
new_pool = batch.models.PoolAddParameter(
            id=pool_id,
            virtual_machine_configuration=batch_models.VirtualMachineConfiguration(
                image_reference=image_ref_to_use,
                node_agent_sku_id=sku_to_use),
            vm_size=constants._POOL_VM_SIZE,
            target_dedicated_nodes=constants._POOL_NODE_COUNT,
            max_tasks_per_node=2,
            task_scheduling_policy=batch.models.TaskSchedulingPolicy(
                node_fill_type=batch.models.ComputeNodeFillType.pack),
            start_task=batch.models.StartTask(
                command_line=azure_helper.wrap_commands_in_shell('linux', task_commands),
                user_identity=batch_models.UserIdentity(auto_user=user),
                wait_for_success=True,
                resource_files=self.application_files),
            network_configuration=batch_models.NetworkConfiguration(subnet_id=constants.AZURE_BATCH_SUBNET_ID),
        )

        try:
            self.batch_client.pool.add(new_pool)
        except batch_models.batch_error.BatchErrorException as err:
            print_exception()
            raise
```

it gives me `azure.batch.models.batch_error.BatchErrorException: {'lang': u'en-US', 'value': u'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nTime:2018-02-01T15:36:25.5107368Z'}`

If I do not specify the `network_configuration` parameter while creating pool, it works with Python SDK. MY subnet id is of the form `/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx-compute/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxxx-compute-vnet/subnets/default`

Can someone point out to me why this might happen? Manually creating Pools are a pain as I have many resource file URLs to be added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Joining your compute pool with a Virtual Network requires authenticating with Azure Active Directory. Please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-virtual-network) for more information. The AAD requirement is listed in the pre-requisites section of that article. Please review that article fully as it underscores other important requirements and restrictions when joining a pool with a virtual network.

You can see a sample of authenticating with AAD with the Python SDK [here](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html#azure-active-directory-authentication).

Comment: I will explore this option and get back to you!